# Array/Data Changes

Tags: php, arrays, function, explode, dynamic-arrays

I am developing a clan website: piratesofpopulous.comli.com/
It is a game's clan website, I wanted to get the game history of my clan members and show them on their profile page,You can see it here:

http://piratesofpopulous.comli.com/user.php?username=Waleed

That page is not published for users and I am still working on it. The problem is I used explode method to explode this page: http://www.popre.net/game.php?u=38456 . Then use the arrays where game's were saved i.e $expl[596].

I am using this code:

```
//Breaking the URL
$url = "$profile_link"; <-- This profile link will be driven from the database, Its saved when user is registered.
parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $params);

//After Breaking putting the value of u in function
function gameStats($u)
{
$result = file_get_contents('http://popre.net/game.php?u='. $u . '');
$expl = explode('"',$result);

echo"<br>Level: $expl[580]<br>";
echo"Players: $expl[596]<br><br>";
echo"Result: $expl[584]<br><br>";
echo"Points: $expl[586]<br><br>";
}
gameStats( $params['u']);
```

**I am breaking the url because the users are registered using a url
 like this i.e: www.popre.net/user.php?u=38456  <-- Link
 contains user.php?u=someid**

**But the games are saved at game.php not in user.php i.e: `www.popre.net/game.php?u=38456`  <-- game.php/u=same_user_id**

I broke the url to to get the value of "u" from their profile link and then put it in game.php to get arrays, Then show the selective arrays......

You can view all arrays by:

```
print_r($expl);
```

But the problem is that, For few mins examply the explode array $expl[596] is changed to something else containing other data i.e $expl[580], But after few more mins it changes back to $expl[596]. Then the data and games are shown correctly. You can view the page on which I am showing these here: http://piratesofpopulous.comli.com/user.php?username=Waleed  I am still working on it.

So, Is there any way to get the perfect array number So the data is permanently shown without showing any other data?

Or any other method that works if the arrays are changed?

Or any thing else?

Any help would be good for me.....

EDIT:

I am doing this to get the Map(game level),Players,Result and Points.
But after sometime the explode array i.e:Player $expl[600]; changed to $expl[596],It keeps changing but after sometimes it will get back to $expl[600].Is there anyway to still get data from it while it keeeps changing?

This is my code that I am using:

```
            $url = "$profile_link"; <-- You can use this profile link http://popre.net/user.php?u=38456
            parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $params);
            function gameStats($u)
            {
            $result = file_get_contents('http://popre.net/game.php?u='. $u . '');
            $expl = explode('"',$result);

            echo"<div id='games'>";
            echo"<h3>Game 1</h3>";
            echo"<div class='data'>Level:    $expl[584]</div><br>";
            echo"<div class='data'>Player:   $expl[600]</div><br><br>";
            echo"<div class='data'>Result:   $expl[588]</div><br><br>";
            echo"<div class='data'>Points:   $expl[590]</div><br><br></b>";
            echo"</div>";

            }
            gameStats( $params['u']);
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show us the var_dump($result); ?

Comment: var_dump? I don't have any variable like that, I have explained everything in my question, Those are all the functions and variables used in my code to get the matches.

Comment: Put the whole code in a new index.php file, Use the url http://popre.net/user.php?u=38456 instead of $profile_link, You will see the result for that function....

Comment: `var_dump()` is a function provided by PHP that allows you to inspect the content and type of a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) .

eg: for all script

```
$url = "www.popre.net/user.php?u=38456";
parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $params);

function gameStats($u){
    $result = file_get_contents('http://popre.net/game.php?u='. $u . '');
    $return = array();
    $pattern = "\<td rowspan=\"2\" class=\"gamelevel\">\<span><a href=\"(.*)\">(.*)<\/a><\/span>\n(.*)<a href=\"(.*)\">(.*)<\/a><\/td>\n(.*)<td class=\"gamepointsresult dgame(.*)\">(.*)<\/td>(.*)<td class=\"gamepoints\">(.*)<\/td><td class=\"gamepoints\">(.*)<\/td><td class=\"gamepoints\">(.*)<\/td>\n(.*)<tr class=\"(one|two)\"><td colspan=\"4\" class=\"gameplayerssmall\">(.*)vs.(.*)<\/td>\<\/tr>";
    $match = preg_match_all('/'.$pattern.'/', $result, $matches);

    /* level */      foreach($matches[2] as $num => $one){ $return[$num]['level'] = $one; }
    /* map */        foreach($matches[5] as $num => $one){ $return[$num]['map'] = $one; }
    /* result */     foreach($matches[8] as $num => $one){ $return[$num]['result'] = $one; }
    /* points */     foreach($matches[10] as $num => $one){ $return[$num]['points'] = strip_tags($one); }
    /* mu */         foreach($matches[11] as $num => $one){ $return[$num]['mu'] = strip_tags($one); }
    /* sigma */      foreach($matches[12] as $num => $one){ $return[$num]['sigma'] = strip_tags($one); }
    /* player1 */    foreach($matches[15] as $num => $one){ $return[$num]['player1'] = strip_tags($one); }
    /* player2 */    foreach($matches[16] as $num => $one){ $return[$num]['player2'] = strip_tags($one); }

    return $return;
}

$gameInfo = gameStats($params['u']);

echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td>NO</td><td>LEVEL</td><td>MAP</td><td>RESULT</td><td>POINTS</td><td>MU</td><td>SIGMA</td><td>Player 1</td><td>Player 2</td>
        </tr>\n";

foreach($gameInfo as $num => $one){
    echo "<tr>
        <td>".($num+1)."</td><td>".$one['level']."</td><td>".$one['map']."</td><td>".$one['result']."</td><td>".$one['points']."</td><td>".$one['mu']."</td><td>".$one['sigma']."</td><td>".$one['player1']."</td><td>".$one['player2']."</td>
    </tr>\n";
}

echo "</table>";
```

You will get all results in that `array`, same for the others, then combine the array, as all results will have same number of elements in every array.

Comment: Same thing ... you will always get all data with what I've told you .. In my case all data for levels ... you should do the same for all stats

Comment: I don't know how to do it using your method, I tried but no success.
I am new to PHP, Can you do it for me, Only for levels I will do it by myself for all other things.


Thanks

Comment: Reply back, My question below.

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't create the whole script, Because I only have basic knowledge about PHP, I watched a tutorial on youtube about currency converter and I used it to do this, But It was not correctly working. Thanks for making the whole script for me, I will be practising it and write the whole script by myself.
Thanks Allot!

Comment: You should know that if the host site will make any change this script will most likely not work. I hope you managed to use it.

Comment: Thanks for telling that, If they change their script, I will change this by myself then.Thanks for every help...

Comment: By the Way, If I want to display only 10 games not 100 games then?

Comment: `for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){` and replace `$num` with `$i`

Answer (score 0):

Just change the value of echo To > $#echo_$expl_Levelname < if you are using Joomla or JavaScript...It will work for sure...Reply  below

Comment: I am unclear what you are suggesting here, perhaps from my inexperience from Joomla. Are you suggesting replacing the `echo` call with `> $#echo_$expl_Levelname <` or `$#echo_$expl_Levelname` , or the string that is `echo`ed with one of the two options. Perhaps if you add tic characters around what is intended to be code, or provide a code example I will be able to understand better.